# What does the /V1 parameter do for Schtasks.exe?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

Microsoft's definition is not too helpful

/V1
A value that creates a task visible to Windows 2000, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP platforms.

Windows XP and Windows Server 2003:  This option is not available.

What would be a typical scenario this flag is used for?

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote that /V1 automatically populates the Start In field. It is annoying that there is no flag to set the Start In folder, but maybe /V1 takes care of that. Give it a try.